# Is this flying bug swarm termites? Found in New York city, approx 7mm

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Just saw a giant swarm of these fly out in between pavers and a door sill from a small crack in the ground here in New York City.  There seemed to be hundreds of them swarming out very quickly.  They are about ant-sized.  Are they termites?

Here are photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks to be [*Reticulitermes flavipes*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/termites/native_subterraneans.htm) aka the [Eastern Subterranean Termite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_subterranean_termite).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus not appropriate for this site. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 